# Pass Setter from Parent to Child Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, syncfusion

In Blazor Server Side, how can I pass a setter method from a parent component to a child? This seems super simple but I'm just not making it work.

In the parent (a Syncfusion tabs "wizard" component) there's vars to determine whether or not a tab should be enabled. So in the parent there's something like

```
<SfTab CssClass="BlazorTab" @bind-SelectedItem="SelectedPage" LoadOn="ContentLoad.Demand">
    <TabItems>
        <TabItem>
            <ChildContent>
                <TabHeader Text="Select Media"></TabHeader>
            </ChildContent>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div id="mediaSelect">
                    <div class="wizard-title">Media Selection</div>
                            <ImageUploader SetMediaOption="@SetMediaOption" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="btn-container">
                            <SfButton >Upload media</SfButton>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Disabled="@MediaOptions">
            <ChildContent>
                <TabHeader Text="Select Options"></TabHeader>
            </ChildContent>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div id="mediaOptions">
                    <div class="wizard-title">Select media import options</div>
                    
                    <br />
                    <div class="btn-container">
                        <SfButton @onclick="@SelectMediaPrevious">Previous</SfButton>
                        <SfButton @onclick="@SelectMediaNext">Next</SfButton>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </TabItem>
@code{
    public bool MediaOption { get; set; } = true; // disabled initially
    public void SetMediaOption(bool Value)
    {
        MediaOption = Value;
    }
}
```

The child component (`ImageUploader`) needs to change the value of `MediaOption` from `true` (disabled) to `false` (enabled) when there's at least one image uploaded. However, I can't seem to get the right `type` defined for the app to compile. Is it possible to just pass in the actual `MediaOption` getter / setter, or do I need to do the `SetMediaOption` method? If so, how do I define the parameter in the child component?

I've tried many variations of

```
[Parameter]
public EventCallback<bool> SetMediaOption { get; set; }
```

but the parent variable isn't changed (or it just fails to compile since the params type is incorrect)

Comment: You haven't shared the child, but I'm assuming you call `SetMediaOption?.InvokeAsync(true);` at some point in your child.  Your event handler is `void`, which (I believe) will not trigger  StateHasChanged authomatically.  So you should add `StateHasChanged()` at the end of the `SetMediaOption` method.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 thanks, you helped me a ton. If you like, leave that as the answer and I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shared the child, but I'm assuming you call `SetMediaOption?.InvokeAsync(true);` at some point in your child. Your event handler is void, which (I believe) will not trigger `StateHasChanged` authomatically. So you should add `StateHasChanged()` at the end of the `SetMediaOption` method.

Another option, that I didn't mention in my original post, is that you can change your event-handling method to `async Task` rather than `void`.

Last thing, if you DO use an `async Task`, and you want to call `StateHasChanged` in the middle for some reason, use `await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)` instead of `StateHasChanged()`

Answer (score 0):

In the Syncfusion blazor **release 20.2.39**, an issue with Disable state of the tab item not working properly has been fixed. So, you can resolve the problem by upgrading the Syncfusion blazor packages version to the latest.

**Release notes:** https://blazor.syncfusion.com/documentation/release-notes/20.2.39?type=all#tab